# Web Dynos in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cron, scheduler

I just wanted to see what the best practice in the following situation would be.

I have setup scheduler in my heroku app to run two rake tasks, (performs a screen scrape), these are ran once a day, now from what i have read i have 750 hours free per month of dyno processes but you accrue usage even when the dyno is idle.. So do i need to run

```
 heroku ps:scale web=0
```

so that the dyno doesnt accrue usage when not running or do i just leave it as it is?

What is the best thing to do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't added any more web workers then you should be on the free tier. If you log into your Heroku account and go to the app's dashboard you'll see an estimated monthly cost for resources used, you can double check that it's on `$0`.

I tested both `heroku ps:scale web=0` and `heroku ps:scale web=1` on one of my apps. Both leave the cost at `$0`, and the app is still online even with 0 web workers, so I'm not sure how that works.

You will however pay for the scheduler, for the time it was up to call the rake task. Might be a few dollars per month, or perhaps less than a dollar, depends how long it was up for.

Comment: many thank fro your answer, so my output is === web (1X): `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT`
web.1: idle 2013/05/04 18:19:02 (~ 2h ago)..the task takes no longer than 10 seconds so i guess im ok, though even if its a few dollars its not going to matter

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer as I did a few tests since writing it.